# Issues with sending emails from SSRS reports "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Tags: reporting-services, smtp

I have been attempting to get data-driven subscriptions (or subscriptions of any kind) to work with no success. I have the SMTP settings in the rsreportserver.config set to match the same settings as we have for SQL Server Database Mail.

However when I run my data-driven subscriptions report from SSRS, I receive the folowing error message.

"at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

My server is running Windows 2019 standard for SSRS.  I was able able to test the connnection for my database with a sucessful pass as well.  Any ideas as to what else I am missing here?

My server is running Windows 2019 standard for SSRS.  I was able able to test the connnection for my database with a sucessful pass as well.  Any ideas as to what else I am missing here?

I ran IISCrypto and TLS 1.2 is the only item checked under server protocols.  I can run a test using https://www.smtper.net/ with my smtp host smtp.sendgrid.net , port 587, and my username and password with a succesful result.